# sed usage in x loader Makefile

Tags: linux, sed, makefile

What does this sed command do? when i run `uname -m` on my pc, it returns `x86_64`.

```
HOSTARCH := $(shell uname -m | \
sed -e s/i.86/i386/ \
    -e s/sun4u/sparc64/ \
    -e s/arm.*/arm/ \
    -e s/sa110/arm/ \
    -e s/powerpc/ppc/ \
    -e s/macppc/ppc/)
```

Note: code snippet from x loader Makefile.

Comment: Do they not have a `man` command on your linux machine?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about linux administration (unix.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sed` tries to show what system you run with a more readable name.

Eks if you have `i.86` it shows `i386`

But the one who made the script did forget the intel 64 bits `x86_64`.

Comment: This seems like a normalization attempt. So `i386`, `i586`, and `i686` all show up as `i386`, the various mac platforms end up as `ppc`, etc. This may or may not have missed `x86_64` I'm betting not though I'm betting that's self-normalized.